# WPF ошибка CS1061 с ссылкой на XAML-файл

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-canvas

Вот код С#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;


namespace WpfApp2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainPage : Window
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        DispatcherTimer enemyTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        DispatcherTimer targetTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        bool humanCaptured = false;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            enemyTimer.Tick += enemyTimer_Tick;
            enemyTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

            targetTimer.Tick += targetTime_Tick;
            targetTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.1);
        }

        private void targetTime_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            progressBar.Value += 1;
            if (progressBar.Value >= progressBar.Maximum)
            {
                EndTheGame();
            }
        }

        private void EndTheGame()
        {
            if (!playArea.Children.Contains(gameOverText))
            {
                enemyTimer.Stop();
                targetTimer.Stop();
                humanCaptured = false;
                StartButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                playArea.Children.Add(gameOverText);
            }
        }

        private void enemyTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {

        }

        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddEnemy();
        }

        private void AddEnemy()
        {
            ContentControl enemy = new ContentControl();
            enemy.Template = Resources["EnemyTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
            AnimateEnemy(enemy, 0, playArea.ActualWidth - 100, "(Canvas.Left)");
            AnimateEnemy(enemy, random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100),
                random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100), "(Canvas.Top)");
            playArea.Children.Add(enemy);
        }
        private void AnimateEnemy(ContentControl enemy, double from, double to, string propertyToAnimate)
        {
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard { AutoReverse = true, RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever };
            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                From = from,
                To = to,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(4, 6)))
            };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, enemy);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(propertyToAnimate));
            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
            storyboard.Begin();
        }
    }
}
```

А вот это часть на которую ссылается ошибка

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="20" ValueChanged="ProgressBar_ValueChanged"/>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама ошибка на скриншоте или вот текстом:

> Error CS1061  'MainPage' does not contain a definition for
>   'ProgressBar_ValueChanged' and no accessible extension method
>   'ProgressBar_ValueChanged' accepting a first argument of type
>   'MainPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Новая ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас вот это `ProgressBar` нверное в файлике `MainPage.xaml` лежит? Можете показать начало этого файлика?

Comment: ну и как бы не видно в вашем классе `MainPage` метода `ProgressBar_ValueChanged`, о чем вам явно пишет ошибка. Что вам а ней не понятно?

Comment: `private void ProgressBar_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<T> e)
        {

        }
`

Если этот метод просто добавлять путём дабл.клика по прогресБару в wpf, то я не понимаю, что означает второй аргумент и почему там заведомо ошибка. И при этом основная ошибка не исчезает. 

В случае ручного создания метода ProgressBar_ValueChanged ситуация с ошибкой так же не меняется

Comment: И вот начало файла которое вы просили

`<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Save the Humans" Height="450" Width="800">`

Comment: откуда вы вообще взяли вот это? `private void ProgressBar_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<T> e) { }`, почему не `private void ProgressBar_ValueChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e){}` ?

Comment: потому что `ProgressChangedEventArgs` не тип и не пространство имён и двойном клике в файле XAML по Progress Bar, автоматически создаётся метод, который я скинул вместе с аргументом `RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<T>`

Comment: `ProgressChangedEventArgs не тип и не пространство имён` это у вас в проекте такое пространство имен? В дотнете такого пространства нет.

Comment: Это так ошибка говорит, когда я ввожу написанный вам метод

Comment: Покажите скрин и текст ошибки

Comment: Я прикрепил скрин к основному вопросу, ибо в комментарии скрины кидать нельзя

Comment: Всё, проблему решил, вроде. По крайней мере программа стартует и ошибок нет. А решить её помогла русская версия студии и её совет сделать этот аргумент метода таким 

`private void ProgressBar_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {

        }`